# File to Upload has a restricted extension

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I used the Valence site to retrieve the SDK for ASP.NET.  After modification I attempted to upload my aspx and aspx.cs file to my test course located in my company's D2L site.  When I clicked upload I get this:  "File to Upload has a restricted extension".  This surprises me since I got the .NET code from D2L.

Is this something that our site administrator changes or something that D2L changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

C# files are restricted due to the way ASP.NET can perform dynamic compilation. That restriction will not be lifted.

If you are uploading the C# files for students to look at, you can zip the solution folder or appropriate files and upload the resulting zip archive.

If you intend to use the the ASP.NET page to serve up dynamic content, you have a couple options. You could re-code your app in JavaScript and host it in the content area. Alternatively, you could host your ASP.NET site on another server and create a content topic that links out to your page on that server.